# Create a maven archetype to generate multiple classes from one class template

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I created a custom maven archetype that has a ClassName.java class that contains a property ${propertyName} with its getter and setter.

```
package ${package};

// Start of user code (import)

// End of user code (import)

/**
 * Block ${BlockName}
 */
public class ${BlockName} extends Block<${BlockName}DTO> {

    /**
     * Item  ${itemName}
     */
    private final Item<${itemType}> ${itemName} = new Item.Control<${itemType}>(this, "${itemName}") {

    };

    // Getter and Setter

}
```

What I want to achieve when creating a new project from this custom archetype is giving multiple class names (for example: Car, Bicycle ...), and give also multiple properties for each class (for example: Car.door, Car.window, Bicycle.wheel ...), and have as output the classes created from the template ClassName.java as Car.java and Bicycle.java, but in each class have the ${itemName}, getters and setters replaced with the properties given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably code a groovy script for that and run it post-generation

[Is there a way to post-process project generated from archetype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19564804/927493)

On the other hand: Generating getters/setters is standard IDE functionality (e.g. easily done in Eclipse), so I am not sure whether this is really useful in an archetype.

Comment: Thank you for answering !

I have other methods to generate for each property other than the getters/setters.

Comment: I added more clarification to my post.

Comment: I tried your solution and it's working, thank you very much!